# Scene Kit node not rotating

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to rotate by scene kit node, however it is not rotating.

I want it to rotate around the y axis. It is a sphere.

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "diffuse.png")
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIImage(named: "specular.png")
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = UIImage(named: "emission.png")
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)


let action = SCNAction.rotate(by:360 * CGFloat((Double.pi)/180.0), around: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0), duration: 8)

let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(action)
node.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain it isn't rotating? I'm not sure what your diffuse, specular and emission images are but maybe because it's a sphere it just doesn't really look like it is rotating because it looks the same from all sides.

Running the same action on a cube in viewDidAppear is working for me, so it could just be that you can't really notice the sphere rotating. I used this code:

```
    let node = SCNNode()

    node.geometry = SCNBox (width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 0.5, chamferRadius: 0.1)
    node.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -1)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

    let action = SCNAction.rotate(by:360 * CGFloat((Double.pi)/180.0), around: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0), duration: 8)

    let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(action)
    node.runAction(repeatAction)
```

The cube is rotating fine with the way that you rotated the SCNNode.

Hope this helps